# Excel Super long sumifs formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ok I have a massive long sum/sumifs formula I have given a small block below it goes on from cell H8 to cell H221. which requires me to write a massive long formula. there has got to be a better way than this.

```
=SUM(
SUMIFS(Report!H8,Report!H7,"Savings",Report!E7,"DAR"),
SUMIFS(Report!H10,Report!H9,"Savings",Report!E9,"DAR"),
SUMIFS(Report!H12,Report!H11,"Savings",Report!E11,"DAR"),
SUMIFS(Report!H14,Report!H13,"Savings",Report!E13,"DAR")....)
```

the aim of the formula is to look at ad up a cell if it matches a department and a type of money. However the money cell has a cell above saying the type of money and a cell below it that has the type of money below that. example below.

```
deposit    
54    
credit    
98
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your formula just adds each "component" manually, so instead of automating it actually makes your work more messy. I'd use the rows' indices to determine what to do with each row. I'm gonna need a better example to help further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum_range` and `criteria_range#` don't have to start on the same rows, they just have to be the same length.  This means that you can offset your `sum_range` by 1 row:

```
=SUMIFS(Report!H$8:H$221, Report!H$7:H$220, "Savings", Report!E$7:$E220, "DAR")
```

This is roughly equivalent to having a formula in column I where I1 has `=H2`, etc, and then doing the Sum on column I instead of H

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional column  having 1 or 0 for each row if it meets the requirements of department and type of money.

And then a SUM of all rows having a 1 in the new column, as only the ones with 1 will meet the criteria.

This solution involves adding an additional column that wasn't there... so not sure if it's suitable for your specific development.